# How to remove neo4j COMPLETE?

Tags: neo4j

Installing neo4j at arch with `yay -S neo4j-community` and starting with `systemctl start neo4j` I open `http://localhost:7474/browser/` and execute the demo command `create database movies` but I get the error

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.NotSystemDatabaseError
Unsupported administration command: CREATE DATABASE movies
```

because of desperation I tried to remove neo4j completely but he still "remembers" my initial password and also still has a reference to graph.db that I have removed manually in the menubar.

Where are the files neo4j stores and does someone have idea to fix the problem with the database creation?

Comment: I'm don't know much about yay, are you using PC or MAC?

Comment: Arch Linux 5.11.14-arch1-1